# Postgres select based on true condition from another select

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm a bit new to postgres and quite rusty with SQL.

I have a `users` table with `password_hash` column which stores a hashed password through `pgcrypto`.

```
id  |    name    |      email      |           password_hash            |
----+------------+-----------------+------------------------------------+
  1 | john doe   | jdoe@example.net| $1$47i7aL0t$bUUZWSNhu.KBuFBlwYN3x1 |
```

Verifying whether a user's password is valid can be achieved with this select:

```
SELECT password_hash = crypt('password123', password_hash) FROM users where email='jdoe@example.net';
```

This returns `t` or `f` depending on whether the password matches.

As part of my authorization logic, I need to return the user's row if the password is valid, but I would like to achieve this in a single query instead of first doing the SELECT on the password_hash and then doing another SELECT to retrieve the user's row. What would be the best way to construct a query to do this?

Comment: `select * from users where crypt('password123', password_hash) = 't' and email = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the password check down to `WHERE` section, then make sure both the email `AND` password are correct:

```sql
SELECT users.* FROM users
WHERE password_hash=crypt('pass123',password_hash) 
AND email='jdoe@example.net';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
SELECT
  u.*, 
  password_hash = crypt('password123', password_hash) as valid
FROM users u
WHERE email='jdoe@example.net';
```

Comment: Thanks, this works as well. @Zegarek's answer suits my requirements best